# "Using" in xaml namespaces for Assembly versions?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

So I've seen the usual standard for XML namespaces as

```
xmlns:"clr-namespace:My.Package;assembly=Some.Assembly"
```

Recently on another SO answer, however, I saw someone replace that with

```
xmlns:"using:My.Package"
```

I'm looking for more information on this syntax. Specifically, I'm having an issue where I need to specify the version of the assembly being used, as specified in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyname(v=vs.110).aspx

`clr-namespace` doesn't seem to pay attention to the version flag, and is just using the most recent version of the assembly it can find included in the project.

Comment: Please state your real question in a more focused, clear way. You start out asking about `clr-namespace` vs `using`, but then you later seem to actually be asking about assembly versions.

Comment: While the `using` syntax is a new alternative to the `clr-namespace` (IIRC it's UWP-only), I don't see how it would address a versioning issue. In fact, I don't believe that you can restrict your assembly reference in XAML to a specific version. This would be something you would specify when you add the assembly as a reference to your project itself; it's not needed in the XAML. See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/xaml-namespaces-and-namespace-mapping and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/xaml-overview